# _hideForKeyboardAppearance error when clicking on UITextView

Tags: ios, ios8, uitextview

I have a `UITextView`, and whenever I click on it, the app crashes with the following error:

> -[__NSSetM _hideForKeyboardAppearance]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fb8aa76cd60

If I run the app multiple times, it always crashes at the same place, but the intercepting object that is throwing the "unrecoginzed selector" can be different. Sometimes it is `UIImage` instead of `NSSetM`, sometimes, it is a `UIConstraint`, etc.

Even if I don't assign the `UITextView` to a specific outlet in my class, or have it assigned to a delegate, I get the same behavior. This happens on both simulator and hardware.

Any ideas what is going on?

p.s. this is iOS 8. Crash happens on both iPhone and iPad.

Edit: Note that this happens even though **the UITextView calls no code**.  I removed any outlet connections in the storyboard, and even made it so my class doesn't implement `UITextViewDelegate`. Still crashes. That is why I am so puzzled and wondered if anyone has ever encountered something like this. One thing to note is that the view controller having this issue is buried several screens deep within a `UISplitViewController`. Not sure if someone UI elements buried deep in the nav stack are somehow intercepting the keyboard call?

Comment: Can you please show the block of code with the offending line?

Comment: and format your question a little (use code blocks etc)